# Plotly: Pass array to 'fillcolor' argument

Tags: colors, plotly

I am trying to pass a array of colors to the 'fillcolor' argument to conditionally color the area below a graph.

First, passing a string with the color or rgba code to the 'fillcolor' argument works perfectly fine:

```
fig.add_trace(
        go.Scatter(x=x,
                   y=y,
                   mode='lines',
                   fill='tozeroy',
                   fillcolor='red',
                   line=dict(color='rgba(255, 0, 0, 0.9)')))
```

When passing an array to the 'fillcolor' argument, such as

```
fig.add_trace(
  go.Scatter(x=x,
             y=y,
             name='price',
             mode='lines',
             fill='tozeroy',
             fillcolor=np.where(y > -5, 'green', 'red'),
             line=dict(color='rgba(255, 0, 0, 0.9)')))
```

leads to this error:

```
ValueError: 
    Invalid value of type 'numpy.ndarray' received for the 'fillcolor' property of scatter
```

Also, passing an array directly or passing 'fillcolor=dict(color=array)', does not work.

Is there a chance to pass an array of colors and hence fill the area to the axis conditionally?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: The API indicates that `fillcolor` is to be a single colour (https://plotly.com/python/reference/scatter/#scatter-fillcolor). It doesn't look like Plotly supports multiple fill colours for scatter-fill plots. A last resort would probably be breaking the plot up into multiple traces.

Comment: Thanks for the idea of splitting it up into multiple traces. I read the API documentation. Unfortunately, it is not feasible since my graph consits of hundreds to thousands of scatter points.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- as per comments **fillcolor** is not an array - it is an attribute of a trace
- to achieve a multi-color figure you require a trace for each color line (filled line) required in figure
- have uses **pandas** and **Plotly Express** in this solution, using your original code to set it up
- this does give a marginally different shape plot due to way `tozeroy` works

```
import numpy as np
import plotly.graph_objects as go

x = np.linspace(0, 20, 100)
y = np.random.randint(-7, 3, 100)
fig = go.Figure()
fig.add_trace(
    go.Scatter(
        x=x,
        y=y,
        mode="lines",
        fill="tozeroy",
        fillcolor="red",
        line=dict(color="rgba(255, 0, 0, 0.9)"),
    )
)
fig.show()

# create a dataframe to simplify solution.  green and red lines logic as additional columns
df = pd.DataFrame({"x": x, "y": y})
df = df.assign(
    y_green=np.where(df["y"] > -5, df["y"], 0), y_red=np.where(df["y"] > -5, 0, df["y"])
)

# create the plot
fig = px.line(
    df, x="x", y=["y_green", "y_red"], color_discrete_sequence=["green", "red"]
).for_each_trace(lambda t: t.update(fillcolor=t.line.color, fill="tozeroy"))

fig
```

[image]